# mySQL ordering and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a db table like this:

```
ID     TIME       SUB    INFO
178    9:00AM              A
179    9:10AM              E
180    9:15AM     179      B
181    9:16AM     179      another B
182    9:20AM     179      C
183    9:25AM     179      D
184    9:30AM              F
185    9:35AM     184      before F
```

I need this list to order INFO correctly (A, B, another B, C, D, E, before F, F).
SUB is used when a user inserts new INFO to correct the order. eg, ID180 the user inserted "B" to be positioned before ID179. Likewise, ID181 user inserted "C" to be positioned before 179 as well.

What is the most efficient mysql query to do this ( obviously accounting for non-alphabetical info :P )?

Comment: Are those `INFO` values literally "another B" and "before F"?

Comment: The INFO used here is just an example. The table cant be sorted using the info, rather it can be sorted/ordered by TIME and SUB.

Comment: My original query (which is wrong) was: SELECT * from table WHERE RELATEDTO = '$pid' ORDER BY SUB ASC, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME) DESC; This wont help though...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    <column list>
FROM
    My_Table
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(sub, id + 1),
    `time`
```

This is assuming that the `sub` column is actually `NULL` and not simply blank when it does not have a value. Also, a column named "time" is almost certainly a bad idea since it is not a descriptive name and it is a keyword. Although it is not a reserved word (yet) in MySQL it will likely just cause a lot of confusion. Other examples of poorly named columns might include "info" and "sub".

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID,TIME,SUB,INFO
FROM table1
ORDER BY INFO